# Assignment in model constructor does not work

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a car with two columns: `user_id` and  `token`

I would like to only pass the `user_id` on creation and create a token automatically:

```
$car = Car::create([
        'user_id' => $user->id,
]);
```

this is my car class:

```
class Car extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
      $this->token = mb_substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)),0,8);
    }
```

When I create a car, the `token` field is correctly inserted. However the `user_id` field is null.

When I remove the `__construct()` method, then the `user_id` is correctly inserted (but then there is ofc no token).

I don't understand why the assignment in the constructor removes the `user_id`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Add user_id to the $fillable array in the Car class. `protected $fillable = ['user_id'];`

Comment: @Bryan but I already have specified the `guarded` array. No need for the fillable ne

Comment: Ah, I missed that. You're right. It should work. Are you sure `$user->id` has a value?

Comment: @Bryan yes it has a value. When I delete the constructor from my model, then the column `user_id` gets it correct value assigned.

Comment: I see the issue. Added an answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your constructor doesn't have the correct method signature.

The `create` method in the laravel model creates a new model: `$model = new static($attributes);` The `$attributes` array is what sets the data on your fresh model. You need to make sure your constructor takes the attributes argument and passes it to the parent:

```
public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->token = mb_substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)),0,8);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know where the `create` method is from the class  `Illuminati\Database\Eloquent\Mode.php` ? I checked the class and its trait and I coulnd't find it.

Comment: Depends on your version. I found it in a 5.1 project in the model class. Not sure about newer versions.

Comment: I found the `constructor` but not the `model::create` method. But I am using 5.6, maybe they changed it. Anyway, this is in the scope of another question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: In 5.6 it's in the builder. Called through `__call` magic methods: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating the token in your constructor, you could take advantage of [Laravel's model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events). In short, this allows you to listen for an event (e.g. "created," "updated," etc.), and perform an action on that event. If you replace your constructor with the following, it should solve the issue:

```
public static function boot()
{
    self::created(function ($model) {
        $model->update([
            'token' = mb_substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)),0,8);
        ]);
    });
    // If you're using the SoftDeletes trait, uncomment this line.
    // static::bootSoftDeletes();
}
```

You'll create an instance of your `Car` model in your controller, and then the model event will update that instance with your token.

As an aside: since the token is generated randomly, and seems not to rely on any other data/functions, I don't believe there's any shame in dropping this line:

```
'token' = mb_substr(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(32)),0,8);
```

Into the `create` method in your controller. Based on what you've provided, it would be the simplest way to solve for what you need.

Comment: Yes these are both valid workarounds. But I am still puzzled why the assignment in the tokes causes `user_id` to become null.

Comment: Me too, honestly. I'm not sure where, in the constructor implementation, the model is getting saved. After assigning the token, I'd expect to see something like `$this->save()`. Is it possible that the constructor is actually creating a NEW instance of the Car model, instead of modifying the one you created with the `user_id`?